# Embedding a live RTSP stream of H.264 video in a webpage

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, live-streaming, embedded-video

I have a server providing live H.264 video over a network via RTSP (rtsp://...), and I've been trying to find a way to display the stream to users in their browser (on at least Windows and OS X - Linux is a bonus).  I currently have VLC Player embedded and have it working in both IE9 and Mozilla Firefox 12.0, but it would be ideal if, at most, the user just has to install a plugin for their browser or something similar (as opposed to a whole program).

I am able to use Open Source solutions, but I can't use anything GPL.  A Java applet or anything similar is a possibility.

**Solutions considered so far which didn't seem to work**:

- **HTML5 Video Tag**: Doesn't seem to support live RTSP streams
- **GStreamer (Java Bindings) / OSSBuild GStreamer-WinBuilds v0.10.7 Beta 4 LGPL**:  Plugins seemed flaky with RTSP sources and the WinBuild (my stream gave errors related to a stream SETUP request, while others did not)
- **JavaFX**: Seemed to have dropped support for live RTSP streams in its most recent release
- **Xuggler**: Licensing seems to pose an issue
- **JMF**: Old, no apparent H.264 support
- **FMJ**: Doesn't seem to be any support for live RTSP streams

Should I reevaluate any of these possibilities?
Any other suggestions (such as in Flash or Silverlight) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: it would be really great to get a solution in HTML5.

Comment: If you can replace the rtsp implementation with a [http live streaming implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming), you might want to consider that.  JavaFX 2.2 will support H.264 delivered via HTTP Live Streaming on (at least) Windows/OSX/Linux, but (as you noted) not RTSP delivery. If you do consider this switch then you should also review this [summary of the status of JavaFX 2.1 video support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440152/any-simple-and-up-to-date-java-frameworks-for-embedding-movies-within-a-swing/10441210).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, I'm unable to switch to HTTP live streaming.

Answer (score 12):

Live streaming must be supported by browser, not the HTML5 player. You can refer the documentation here http://www.bitspace.in/2011/02/html5-live-streaming-media-server.html. Also `rtsp` cannot be played using `HTML5` as in http://www.jquery4u.com/flowplayer/html5-video-rtsp-live-streams/#.T9hzRjkpK0x. If you can transcode the video then you might use `HTML5`. For reference you can check the answer from [Convert rtsp video stream to http stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370742/convert-rtsp-video-stream-to-http-stream) or refer the documentation from wowza server for converting stream http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?39-How-to-re-stream-video-from-an-IP-camera-%28RTSP-RTP-re-streaming. In general `rtsp stream` opens with external player if there is no player already embedded in your code but dont know how you can give the message to the user to install any plugin to play the stream and how far this will work across devices and cross-browser. Also there is no support for any of the flash player to handle `rtsp stream` except `http` and `rtmp`.

Answer (score 2):

The internet cameras my company works with has a browser interface that does just this. Annoyingly we don't have access to the source for the embedded video player however the following site appears to have it.

http://en.pudn.com/downloads357/doc/detail1552764_en.html

The extra annoying thing however is that this site requires you to register first and then submit 5 pieces of code to gain access to the download. I haven't complete these uploads yet an feel it may be a white rabbit chase, I only share it as I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

VLC plugin works fine for all platforms you ask about.

Comment: NPAPI is disabled in Google Chrome/Canary very soon. How VLC can be used with Google Chrome/Canary in that case?

Comment: Would love to know the answer as well @YumYumYum. Would love something that doesn't require installing entire VLC

Comment: See http://www.vboxcomm.com/enable-vlc-web-plugin-in-google-chrome-npapi.html?tmpl=component. TL;NR: until September 2015 the user can enable NPAPI manually; by then, VLC will hopefully offer PPAPI support.

Comment: Is there PPAPI support by now, or an alternative to streaming raw `h264`?

Comment: @Redsandro: Not yet; you are definitely [*welcome*](https://wiki.videolan.org/OPW_Summer_2014/#Port_VLC.27s_NPAPI_web_plugin_to_PPAPI) to volunteer to build such.