# How can I play an RTP video stream on web browser?

Tags: streaming, browser, media-player, rtp

I have an incoming RTP stream that I want to render in a web browser. What are the current chances to do this?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/1737065/1860929 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10807567/1860929

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight player - checkout this code:https://github.com/kaltura/chromeless-silverlight
in this player we have mutlicast player that play RTP streams from wowza streaming server.
https://github.com/kaltura/chromeless-silverlight/blob/master/Player/MulticastPlayer.cs

Comment: Is silverlight will be available on all browsers - pc, tablet, phone?

Comment: No - Desktops(Mac/Windows) & some windows tablets and phones