# Decode and render H264 encoded RTSP stream using hardware acceleration in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, h.264, rtsp, hardware-acceleration, rtsp-client

I need to decode and render an H.264 encoded RTSP stream in Google Chrome. Low latency is needed and therefore I need to use hardware acceleration for the decoding process. I have been searching for any PPAPI plugins that can be used to RTSP streaming in Chrome, but I haven't found any. [NPAPI plugins have been removed from Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245040/how-can-i-display-an-rtsp-video-stream-in-a-web-page) so the VLC plugin is no longer an option. [Live streaming is also not supported by the HTML5 player.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807567/embedding-a-live-rtsp-stream-of-h-264-video-in-a-webpage)

How can I, in this scenario, build or use(if available) an RTSP client in Chrome, that decodes and renders the RTSP(H264 encoded stream) in the browser, using hardware acceleration to reduce latency?